# When editing, should I make the question into the one it should be, or the one I now need?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, editing

I am writing a heavy edit to my own question: [Do players know that Wizards don't wear armour?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96394/do-players-know-that-wizards-dont-wear-armour)

ShadowKras mentioned the ability to make a knowledge check to determine class features and abilities. If I had known of this, I would have asked a very different question.

But now that I have this information, and am making a large edit to make the question less terrible, should I:

1. Ask a question that implies I don't know of the feature, and therefore make the answer valid?
2. Ask a question that includes that knowledge, and therefore makes the actually helpful answer invalid?
3. Just... abandon the bad question and ask a new one? (This doesn't seem very ethical, but the easiest solution on a purely personal level.)

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the situation, but in this case it's best to ask a new one. There are several answers already, and changing the question would make them invalid. That fact, plus that you now know something that gives you a new question to ask, tips it substantially towards being simpler, cleaner, and truer to post a new question.